# Drupal 7 - Show Child Taxonomies and content in current taxonomy

Tags: views, taxonomy-terms

I have a site that has multiple levels of "Category" taxonomies with varying content within each level.

I have tried for a couple of days but basically i wish to accomplish the following: When a user clicks on a Category view e.g.. /taxonomy/term/% they are presented with a list of child categories and also a list of content items (if any exist) within the parent category.

I have managed to create a view that will show the list of child categories however i cannot combine this with the default term view.

I have attached a mockup of what i wish to accomplish. Any help is greatly appreciated.

[image: Mockup of what i wish to accomplish]

Thanks so much for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a lot of disabled views that come bundled with Views module (check the list of views). One of those disabled views is a replacement for taxonomy/term/%. So, enable it and do all the modifications you need.

You can attach to the header a view with the list of subcategories, and that would fit your needs.

Comment: Hi, thanks so much for this its exactly what i needed. Days of googling did not produce this answer. I hope this helps others.